# subset numpy array with array mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,7],[3,7,2],[4,4,1]])
```

and another array with the same length:

```
b = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])
```

I would like to subset the elements of `a` that match with a 0 in `b`. That is, I want to get:

```
a_new = [[1,2,3],[4,4,1]]
```

I tried:

```
 b = b.astype(bool)
 a_sub = a[b]
```

but I get the following error:

```
 IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1
```

Although they don't have the same number of elements within each array of arrays, both arrays have the same length (`len(a) == len(b)`).

How can I subset `a`?

Comment: `a[b.astype(bool).ravel()]`?

Comment: It's not `len`, number of elements that matters, but shape/dimensions.  One is (4,3) the other (4,1).  A (4,) shaped mask can index on the first, size 4 dimension.  You want 'rows' of `a`, not elements of it.

Comment: oh thanks @QuangHoang!! that solved my problem!